# Problems Using AVM package for LFG structures

Tags: matrices, linguistics, avm

I am trying to draw LFG f-structure matrices using the avm package (https://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/).

For some reason my avm objects do not respect the \\ command, causing obvious problems.

Some sample code that fails to produce multi-line matrices.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{avm}
\begin{document}

\begin{avm}
  \[one\\ two\\ \]
\end{avm}


\end{document}
```

Which produces something like

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old version of `avm.sty` does not work with the `array` package.  You need to update to version 1.03 available from http://nlp.stanford.edu/cmanning/tex/ .  With this version your sample code produces the expected output:

[image]

Here is the list of file versions I used:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
     avm.sty    
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ***********
```

Comment: For me it produces errors. I had to change `\begin{avm}
  \[one\\ two\\ \]
\end{avm}` to `\begin{avm}
  [one\\ two ]
\end{avm}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've added a list of file versions for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Andrew's answer as it worked for the example I posted.  Later however I ran into other package conflicts with avm, even with the newer version.  I discovered that another solution to the problem is to use the tex style of linebreak `\cr` instead of `\\`.

So another way around this problem is to instead use an expression like the one below.

```
\begin{avm}
  \[one\cr two\cr \]
\end{avm}
```